Potentiometer for Kitchen Fan
I'm exploring the possibility of building a potentiometer for my rangehood fan.  The manufacturer (FanTech) of the fan actually sells one (EC-10VHL) but I'm having a hard time trying to find a supplier in Canada.  I found a image of the EC-10VHL potentiometer that FanTech sells (see below)

I was able to find the the actual POT (51AAAC24B15L) component online at DigiKey (https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/bourns-inc/51AAA-C24-B15L/7650569), but with my limited knowledge of electrical engineering, I'm hoping to get some guidance from the community.
Question to folks,
a) Can someone confirm what the silver component is and what the numbers mean (4.7  35s. 169)? I'm assuming it's a capacitor.
b) I drafted a diagram of how i think everything get's soldered together. Can someone review and check if it make sense.

I'm not sure if I'm going to end up going down this path of building one, but I'm curious.

building a potentiometer for my rangehood fan ... you are trying to build a speed control module, not a potentiometer ... the blue component is a potentiometer ... the whole module is a speed control

Assuming the fan is running off the mains, there has to be more to the circuit.  Also, no one puts one surface mount component (the cap) on a board full of through-hole components.  There almost certainly are more components on the underside of the board, maybe with a TRIAC mounted to the metal frame.

The silver component is in fact a capacitor, the code you read on top of it probably means 4.7uF rated for 35 volts and the 169 is the date code or some series number, the main thing you need to focus is on the rated voltage and the capacitance. You should use a mosfet to drive the motor, the potentiometer in series with the motor will act as a resistor and dissipate power as heat, as long it´s rated for the power the motor consumes, and the motor uses DC, it will work, using a mosfet to drive the motor will be way more efficient.

Cheap speed control modules for fans are typically built around a capacitor that will form an impedance divider, with a purely reactive impedance. So it will reduce the voltage seen by the motor, but without dissipating any power like a resistor would do.
I think that the potentiometer is actually controlling an active element (thyristor, triac), can you take a picture of the other side of the circuit board ? Or maybe the control signal is sent along with the power to the motor and the power switches are inside the motor assembly?

Thanks everyone for their input.  It's good info.   I didn't realize there is potentially more components on the other side of the circuit.  I think I'm going to bow down and live with the stock speed controller.  If i end up getting the EC-10VHL speed controller, I'll post what's on the other side of the circuit for folks who are curious.
